# App name and filename different of an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

Greetings,

My app name(the one that appears on the home screen) contains a special character, if i keep the name of the build(Appname.app) to be the same, it gives some sort of error. If I keep the name of the build without any special character everything works fine. Now we want to upload this app to appstore, I was just wondering if that could get my app rejected(keeping app name and build name different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) state:

3.4 App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

"Should be similar" gives them a lot of leeway, and in fact I've had an app rejected where the names were (I thought) very similar.  But, there's definitely no rule that says they must match exactly, and I'd guess you'll be in good shape if the only difference is a special character.

Comment: is it also important to have the same name of the build(myappname.app)?

Comment: @sole997 I can't find any official policy on that.  I've (successfully) submitted apps that were different by at least one character (displayed name had a space in it, .app name did not).